# How to display localStorage value in a table header?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor, local-storage, tableheader

I have the following js function that is used to get the saved value of an input field:

```
function getSavedValue(e) {
    if (!localStorage.getItem(e)) {
        return "";
    }
    return localStorage.getItem(e);
}
```

The following is an example of how I use this js function:

```
var paymentMonth = document.getElementById("monthHR_PaymentMonth");

paymentMonth.value = getSavedValue("monthHR_PaymentMonth");
```

How can I use this function to grab the paymentMonth value and display it in a table column header?:

```
<th>Payment May 2022</th>
```

Where May 2022 is the value saved.

Comment: `value` is for inputs, Use the `textContent` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I use this function to grab the paymentMonth value and display it in a table column header?:
> You can try to add an id to the `<th></th>`:

```
<th id="monthHR_PaymentMonth"></th>
```

and then use the following code to add text to it:

```
$("#monthHR_PaymentMonth").append(getSavedValue("monthHR_PaymentMonth"));
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me in the right track to what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need the element to have an `id` attribute in order to get it with the `getElementById` function. So add an id to the `<th>`, then use the `textContent` property to add text to it:

```
var paymentMonth = document.getElementById("monthHR_PaymentMonth");

paymentMonth.textContent = getSavedValue("monthHR_PaymentMonth");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const paymentMonth = document.getElementById("monthHR_PaymentMonth");
paymentMonth.innerText = getSavedValue("monthHR_PaymentMonth");
```

use innerText!